# scatter plot does not plot all the points in the array + ternary library

Tags: python, pandas, ternary

I am using the ternary library in python and trying to plot a scatter of points in the ternary plot.
However it appears the below code only plots one single point for each of the 3 scatter calls made.
Can you please advise

```
    scale = 1
    figure, tax = ternary.figure(scale=scale)     
    tax.set_title("Scatter Plot", fontsize=20)          
    tax.boundary(linewidth=2.0)        
    tax.gridlines(multiple=5, color="blue")          
    # Plot a few different styles with a legend        
    points = np.array([df['73_prop']])        
    tax.scatter(points, marker='s', color='red', label="Outflows")      
    points = np.array([df['72_prop']])       
    tax.scatter(points, marker='D', color='green', label="HQLA")       
    points = np.array([df['74_prop']])        
    tax.scatter(points, marker='o', color='blue', label="Inflows")       
    tax.legend()       
    tax.ticks(axis='lbr', linewidth=1, multiple=5)     

    tax.show()
```

Here is the plot i get right now

[image]

```
    In [213]:points 
    Out[213]: 
    array([[ 0.47426346,  0.50559869,  0.50368877, ...,  0.65636812,
     0.56024801,  0.49020411]])
```

P.S. Am trying to mimic what's there on:
https://github.com/marcharper/python-ternary#scatter-plots

I have also tried using certain for loop but hasn't helped.

Comment: Only difference I see is the omnious `points = random_points(30, scale=scale)` function - wich probably only creates 30 random values between 0 and scale. Hope someon helps out - you might want to delete your comment on my question to avoid confusion.

Comment: sure thanks Patrick; fingers crossed

Answer (score 0):

Your input data has the wrong format. You supply a list of flots, you need to supply a list of list of floats: `[ [x1,y1] , [x2,y2], ...]`

This works:

```
import ternary
import numpy as np 

scale = 1
figure, tax = ternary.figure(scale=scale)     
tax.set_title("Scatter Plot", fontsize=20)          
tax.boundary(linewidth=2.0)        
tax.gridlines(multiple=5, color="blue")          

rnd = np.random.random(120)
points = [ [x*x, np.random.random(1) * np.random.random(1) * (1-x)] for x in rnd]
tax.scatter(points, marker='s', color='red', label="Outflows")    


rnd = np.random.random(120)

# [[x1,y1], [x2,y2], ..., [xn,yn]] 
points = [ [x*x, np.random.random(1) * np.random.random(1) * (1-x)] for x in rnd]
tax.scatter(points, marker='D', color='green', label="HQLA")       

rnd = np.random.random(120)
points = [ [x*x, np.random.random(1) * np.random.random(1) * (1-x)] for x in rnd]
tax.scatter(points, marker='o', color='blue', label="Inflows")       

tax.legend()       
tax.ticks(axis='lbr', linewidth=1, multiple=5)     

tax.show()
```

[image]